# jquery cycle plugin divs always stacked problem

Tags: jquery, html

i want to put three jquery slideshows in a div. somehow, without any css positioning the slides wont display below each other, but stacked. how can i get the sildes to display below each other, just as normal divs would?

```
    <div id="slidecontainer" style="background-color: red;">

<div id="q1">
        <img src="merkel01.jpg"/>
        <img src="merkel02.jpg"/>
        <img src="merkel03.jpg"/>
        <img src="merkel04.jpg"/>
        <img src="merkel05.jpg"/>
    </div>

<div id="q2">
        <img src="poyan01.jpg"/>
        <img src="poyan02.jpg"/>
        <img src="poyan03.jpg"/>
        <img src="poyan04.jpg"/>
        <img src="poyan05.jpg"/>
        <img src="poyan06.jpg"/>
  </div>


 <div id="q3">
        <img src="mirage01.jpg"/>
        <img src="mirage02.jpg"/>
        <img src="mirage03.jpg"/>
        <img src="mirage04.jpg"/>
        <img src="mirage05.jpg"/>

  </div>


  <div>TEST</div>
  <div>TEST222</div>
  <div>TEST333</div>

 </div>
```

also, if i add additional test-divs they will also be placed under the three stacked slides... any help vermy much appreciated!!

fusi

Comment: Would this be the cycle plugin you're talking about: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 2):

Could you give us a link to the source code of the cycle plugin?

Even though there *may* be no CSS involved, the plugin can still do this with jQuery which is essentially the same thing: `element.css('position', 'absolute')`

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and suggest you look for anywhere that absolute positioning is applied to the divs and change `absolute` to `static`, as that's the most probable cause of your stacked divs.

**Edit:** found where it's happening, if you're using http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Even though this will *probably* break it from working properly, you should be able to tweak it to your liking afterwards.

Look for this line (259 in jquery.cycle.js):

```
$slides.css({position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0}).hide().each(function(i) {
```

Change it to:

```
$slides.hide().each(function(i) {
```

And remove this line (261):

```
$(this).css('z-index', z)
```

Which is a few lines below.

More info on jQuery's `css` method: http://api.jquery.com/css/